# how to use require in javascript files

Tags: javascript, firebase-admin, javascript-import

in my app.js that is located in the root folder, I mean `Mywebsite/app.js` i can access require variable

```
const express = require("express");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
```

but in all other folders like `public` or `static` or `views` folders, I can not use require and also I can't import any library like this one

```
import admin from "firebase-admin"
```

and im getting this error for import

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'admin'. import call expects exactly one argument.

or this for require

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require

I'm new to web development especially when it comes to using an express app
now all my problem is with require or importing a library in javascript files, is there any other ways to include or call models in nodejs rather than require

here is my dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "csurf": "^1.11.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase": "^8.6.3",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.9.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "popups": "^1.1.3",
    "requirejs": "^2.3.6"
  },
```

Comment: Can you include a [file tree](https://ascii-tree-generator.com) of your project directory?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using `const { admin } = require("firebase-admin");` ?

Comment: after you just sayed i did but im getting the same error `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require` @MehakMehta

Comment: for express.js you can simply use `const express ="express"` . For firebase idk but it should be the same `const {admin} = "firebase-admin"` . If these solutions doesn't work, i apologize i can't help you any further :/.

Answer (score 0):

`const { admin } = require("firebase-admin");` should solve your issue but if it doesn't

Do check the following

- Node Version
- Add a key to `package.josn`, `"main": "app.js"`
- run `npm i`
- run `node app.js` in the root folder

`import admin from "firebase-admin"` won't work as you're not using ES6.